# Is market data api subject to regulatory controls?

Tags: finance, data, market, regulation

I have noticed that many (also paid) market data Apis provide incomplete or sometimes even completely wrong market data. Now I have noticed that almost all providers write in the terms and conditions that they do not give any guarantee on the correctness of the market data. Does this really let the providers off the hook? This means that I could sell market data that comes from a random generator and no one could sue me legally for it? Or are such providers obliged by regulatory authorities to have the quality of the market data independently verified and those who don't do this are just scam?

Comment: This is bit off topic really, but let me give you a slightly different perspective. We purchase data to satisfy regulations for independent daily valuation of positions. We don't want to and would rather use our own data, but we have to. We have an interest to ensure that the data is correct and not overcharged. If it is overcharged we switch providers. If it is erroneous we drop that point and move on. If that happens a lot with the same provider we change to a new one. We would do due diligence on a provider before buying data. A "random sampler" would not get custom and wouldn't keep it.

Answer (score 2):

I would try to approach this question from three angles and put a general statement upfront:

Generally, the terms and conditions of a data vendor cannot dispense them from all wrongdoing, just as any other contract may be deemed unfair. Usually, the leeway for vendors to add restrictive terms to terms and conditions is less than for individually negotiated contracts.

1. Contractual liability: **Yes,** a vendor of a service is bound to the contract that they have with their customer. This contract, first and foremost, is likely the delivery of data. Noncompliance with the contract may lead to the right for a refund and, in the case of gross negligence, a claim for damages. Using a random number generator as you suggest would likely be considered gross negligence. I do not think an authority could legally sue the vendor for this, but the clients could ask for refunds and potentially claim legal damages.
2. Oversight by financial or other authorities: **No,** I'm not aware that data vendors fall under dedicated supervision by financial authorities. So, to your last questions, data providers do not need to have their data "independently verified."
3. Data provision of financial data may implicitly require **extra care** by the vendor to make sure that the data is reliable and accessible at all times. In particular, clients may rely on that data to be technically accessible at certain hours of the day, and with a certain time delay. The requirements for financial data may thus implicitly be higher than for less crucial applications, so data vendors for financial data may be held to higher standards than data vendors of other types of data. Likely, a judge would take into account whether the vendor did the best they could to prevent mistakes and downtime. Furthermore, if a data service is priced highly, offers an API for professional clients, and is marketed as an institutional product, this could likely be held against the vendor. A customer would rightfully assume that such a data product is reliable.

There are surely more legal aspects to this, and differences depending on the jurisdiction. I'm working for a vendor that sells financial data, and I tried to give a practical answer. I'm not a lawyer.